# Replace dark background and square

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, drag-and-drop

Below is an example of a pretty cool angularjs app that has drag-and-drop feature. It uses the ngDraggable module.

http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/35z4J/

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="shape" ng-draggable='dragOptions'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The background is black. User can drag a white square around. I want to do 2 things;

1. Replace the black background with this floorplan.

[image]

2. Replace the white square with this simple image icon.

[image]

How can the jsfiddle be modified to do the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this link

http://jsfiddle.net/35z4J/113/

```
#container {
   width : auto;
   height: 1200px;
   background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZvy.jpg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.shape {
    position: absolute;
    width : 200px;
    height: 500px;
     background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGQbN.png');
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it is working partially. I cannot move the light bulb from upper-left corner to the lower-right corner. It stops halfway. EDIT: It works now! Great job. Wonder if the lightbulb could be made to move only within the image.